# Is it possible to have my entire asp.net site load at once?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I built a website using asp.net that pulls many very advanced queries from SQL server (for an internal tool for my company) the problem i'm having is the time it takes for each page to load because of the queries. Is there a way to just have the queries execute at once while they have a loading screen?

Comment: Having it load all at once may not be the best idea as it may mean a long loading time. Users are very impatient these days and usability and availability should be paramount considerations for a developer. A common way to do things is to ONLY load what they need, and not more.

Comment: They need all of the queries to run exactly how they are so I was just going to put all of the loading time onto one screen in the beginning so they don't get frustrated when browsing.

Comment: Maybe you should also consider optimizing your queries and adding indexes to your tables.

Comment: Are `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel` from `AjaxControlToolkit` an option?